# Remove Duplicate columns from table in Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables A and B. Both tables have 58 columns per table.

**Table "A" has Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, A1, A2, A3,...,A53.**

**Table "B" has Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, B1, B2, B3,...,B53.**

I have used FULL OUTER JOIN. 
And
I have output,

My Output table "MOT" has **Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5**, A1, A2, A3,...,A53, **Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5**, B1, B2, B3,...,B53.

I want following output.

Output Table "OT" has **Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, A1, A2, A3,...,A53, B1, B2, B3,...,B53**.

So i do not want duplicate columns in the output.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to decide if you wanted the columns [Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5]  From table A or B and alias appropriately.

Example:
Alias Table 'A' as 'a' then

```
Select

a.Column1,a.Column2,a.Column3, a.Column4, a.Column5, A1, A2, A3,...,A53, B1, B2, B3,...,B53
```

Comment: But if i want to select a.Column1,a.Column2,a.Column3, a.Column4, a.Column5, A1, A2, A3,...,A53, B1, B2, B3,...,B53 than do i have to write all the column names or i can just exclude b.Column1, b.Column2, b.Column3, b.Column4, b.Column5 from *.

Comment: You could  select  a.*, B1,..,B53

Comment: I believe you would have to list all of the column names for the columns that don't fall under a.*

Comment: @C ya i understood. You can look at my answer which i posted. I used dynamic query. I was actually searching for short method such as any keyword like EXCLUDE or something.

Comment: One way or the other the columns must be listed out if they are to be selected

Answer (score 0):

I used loop and generate dynamic query. This will exclude the B.Column1, B.Column2, B.Column3, B.Column4, B.Column5 from the table.

```
DECLARE @sel VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @frm VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @counter INT

SET @counter = 1
SET @sel = 'select A.*';
SET @temp = '';
SET @frm = ' from table';
SET @columnName = ' , B';

WHILE @counter <= 53
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = @temp + @columnName + cast(@counter as varchar(4));
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    END
SET @columnName = @sel + @temp + @frm;
EXEC(@columnName);
```